# Value is correct in text but incorrect in .attr() or .html()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a dynamic filter which filters the results in a side `div`. Note that I am using `D3` in my code.

My problem is that I can present the text of the selection in the `div` but I cannot create a link that will redirect to another page. In the first snippet, the value is set to undefined. In the second snippet, I cannot present the `a href` tag at all.

```js
var json_data = {"headers":["Week","Web Page","Image","Number"],"rows":[["2018-09-24 00:00:00.0","/blue","https://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/2012/82/d78470a4-3812-4faf-bfc8-e525d02378d1.png",193],["2018-10-08 00:00:00.0","/red","https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbows/images/5/5a/Red.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111028211830",127],["2018-09-17 00:00:00.0","/green","https://www.creativeglassshop.co.uk/userfiles/productlargeimages/product_2747.jpg",87]]};
  
var dataRows = json_data.rows;

/* ----- !Data ----- */

/* ----- Functions ----- */


//Filter creation function
filterCreation = () => {

  //Clear the filter in case of reload
  d3.select(".selector").remove();

  // Get names of unique Values, for filter list 
  var values = [["/blue","/red","/green"],["https://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/2012/82/d78470a4-3812-4faf-bfc8-e525d02378d1.png","https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbows/images/5/5a/Red.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111028211830","https://www.creativeglassshop.co.uk/userfiles/productlargeimages/product_2747.jpg"]];

  var filter = d3.select("#filter")
    .insert("ul", "svg")
    .classed('selector', true)

  filter.selectAll("li")
    .data(values[0])
    .enter().append("li") 
      .html(function(d,i) {
       return '<img src="' + values[1][i] + '"/><br><span class="siteText">' + values[0][i] + '</span>';
      })
    .on("click", filterSelect);

}


//Filter Select function. It updates the data, after selecting one option from the filter list
var filterSelect = function(d) {

  data = [{"date":"2018-09-24","Value":"/blue","num":193,"img":"https://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/2012/82/d78470a4-3812-4faf-bfc8-e525d02378d1.png"},{"date":"2018-10-08","Value":"/red","num":127,"img":"https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbows/images/5/5a/Red.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111028211830"},{"date":"2018-09-17","Value":"/green","num":87,"img":"https://www.creativeglassshop.co.uk/userfiles/productlargeimages/product_2747.jpg"}];

  d3.select("svg").remove();

  const newData = data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.Value == d;
  });

  // get the parent ul element, remove `active` class from children
  this.parentNode.childNodes.forEach((e) => {
    e.classList.remove('active');
  });
  // mark this node as active
  this.classList.add('active');
  //Appends chart headline
  
  d3.select(".g-hed").text(d);

  d3.select(".g-intro")
    .html(function(d,i) {
    //console.log(d);
    return '<a href="https://www.random.com/' + d + '">'+ d +'</a>';
})    


};

/* ----- !Functions ----- */

/* ----- Main ----- */

filterCreation();
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla);body{font-family:Karla,sans-serif;font-size:18px;overflow:hidden;color:#555}.flex-container{padding:0;margin:0;list-style:none;display:-webkit-box;display:-moz-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:-webkit-flex;display:flex;-webkit-flex-flow:row wrap;justify-content:space-around}.flex-item1,.flex-item2{height:auto;margin-top:10px;font-weight:700;text-align:center}.flex-item1{width:33%}.flex-item2{width:67%}ul{padding:0;list-style-type:none}.selector li{padding:0;margin:0 0 30px}.active img{opacity:.5;filter:alpha(opacity=50)}.selector{max-height:440px;overflow:auto}li .selector{cursor:auto}li .selector img{width:auto;height:100%;max-height:80px}ul::-webkit-scrollbar{width:.8em}.selector::-webkit-scrollbar-track{-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 6px #F5F5F5;background-color:#F5F5F5}.selector::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background-color:#c7003b}.siteText{font-size:2vw}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item1">
    <div id="filter"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item2">
    <p class="g-intro"></p>
    <p class="g-hed"></p>
    <div class="g-chart"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Another snippet:

```js
var json_data = {"headers":["Week","Web Page","Image","Number"],"rows":[["2018-09-24 00:00:00.0","/blue","https://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/2012/82/d78470a4-3812-4faf-bfc8-e525d02378d1.png",193],["2018-10-08 00:00:00.0","/red","https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbows/images/5/5a/Red.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111028211830",127],["2018-09-17 00:00:00.0","/green","https://www.creativeglassshop.co.uk/userfiles/productlargeimages/product_2747.jpg",87]]};
  
var dataRows = json_data.rows;

/* ----- !Data ----- */

/* ----- Functions ----- */


//Filter creation function
filterCreation = () => {

  //Clear the filter in case of reload
  d3.select(".selector").remove();

  // Get names of unique Values, for filter list 
  var values = [["/blue","/red","/green"],["https://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/2012/82/d78470a4-3812-4faf-bfc8-e525d02378d1.png","https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbows/images/5/5a/Red.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111028211830","https://www.creativeglassshop.co.uk/userfiles/productlargeimages/product_2747.jpg"]];

  var filter = d3.select("#filter")
    .insert("ul", "svg")
    .classed('selector', true)

  filter.selectAll("li")
    .data(values[0])
    .enter().append("li") 
      .html(function(d,i) {
       return '<img src="' + values[1][i] + '"/><br><span class="siteText">' + values[0][i] + '</span>';
      })
    .on("click", filterSelect);

}


//Filter Select function. It updates the data, after selecting one option from the filter list
var filterSelect = function(d) {

  data = [{"date":"2018-09-24","Value":"/blue","num":193,"img":"https://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/2012/82/d78470a4-3812-4faf-bfc8-e525d02378d1.png"},{"date":"2018-10-08","Value":"/red","num":127,"img":"https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbows/images/5/5a/Red.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111028211830"},{"date":"2018-09-17","Value":"/green","num":87,"img":"https://www.creativeglassshop.co.uk/userfiles/productlargeimages/product_2747.jpg"}];

  d3.select("svg").remove();

  const newData = data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.Value == d;
  });

  // get the parent ul element, remove `active` class from children
  this.parentNode.childNodes.forEach((e) => {
    e.classList.remove('active');
  });
  // mark this node as active
  this.classList.add('active');
  //Appends chart headline
  
  d3.select(".g-hed").text(d);
  
  d3.select(".g-intro")
    .append("a")
    .attr({"xlink:href": "#"})
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d, i){ return d; });



};

/* ----- !Functions ----- */

/* ----- Main ----- */

filterCreation();
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla);body{font-family:Karla,sans-serif;font-size:18px;overflow:hidden;color:#555}.flex-container{padding:0;margin:0;list-style:none;display:-webkit-box;display:-moz-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:-webkit-flex;display:flex;-webkit-flex-flow:row wrap;justify-content:space-around}.flex-item1,.flex-item2{height:auto;margin-top:10px;font-weight:700;text-align:center}.flex-item1{width:33%}.flex-item2{width:67%}ul{padding:0;list-style-type:none}.selector li{padding:0;margin:0 0 30px}.active img{opacity:.5;filter:alpha(opacity=50)}.selector{max-height:440px;overflow:auto}li .selector{cursor:auto}li .selector img{width:auto;height:100%;max-height:80px}ul::-webkit-scrollbar{width:.8em}.selector::-webkit-scrollbar-track{-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 6px #F5F5F5;background-color:#F5F5F5}.selector::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background-color:#c7003b}.siteText{font-size:2vw}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item1">
    <div id="filter"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item2">
    <p class="g-intro"></p>
    <p class="g-hed"></p>
    <div class="g-chart"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

***UPD:***

It can work if I change the tag from `p` to `a` and use the following code in the JS bit:

```
d3.select(".g-hed")
            .attr({ "xlink:href": "http://example.com/" + d })
            .text(d);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no data bound to those `.g-intro` paragraphs. Therefore, the first argument (`d`) in the anonymous function inside the `html` method is `undefined`.

Just use the first argument passed to the outer function itself, which is the datum you want:

```
d3.select(".g-intro")
    .html('<a href="https://www.random.com/' + d + '">'+ d +'</a>')
```

By the way, the text shows correctly because in the `text` method you're using the argument passed to the outer function (`text(d)`), not an argument passed to an anonymous function inside it (`text(function(d){return d})`).

Here is your first snippet with that change:

```js
var json_data = {"headers":["Week","Web Page","Image","Number"],"rows":[["2018-09-24 00:00:00.0","/blue","https://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/2012/82/d78470a4-3812-4faf-bfc8-e525d02378d1.png",193],["2018-10-08 00:00:00.0","/red","https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbows/images/5/5a/Red.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111028211830",127],["2018-09-17 00:00:00.0","/green","https://www.creativeglassshop.co.uk/userfiles/productlargeimages/product_2747.jpg",87]]};
  
var dataRows = json_data.rows;

/* ----- !Data ----- */

/* ----- Functions ----- */


//Filter creation function
filterCreation = () => {

  //Clear the filter in case of reload
  d3.select(".selector").remove();

  // Get names of unique Values, for filter list 
  var values = [["/blue","/red","/green"],["https://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/2012/82/d78470a4-3812-4faf-bfc8-e525d02378d1.png","https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbows/images/5/5a/Red.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111028211830","https://www.creativeglassshop.co.uk/userfiles/productlargeimages/product_2747.jpg"]];

  var filter = d3.select("#filter")
    .insert("ul", "svg")
    .classed('selector', true)

  filter.selectAll("li")
    .data(values[0])
    .enter().append("li") 
      .html(function(d,i) {
       return '<img src="' + values[1][i] + '"/><br><span class="siteText">' + values[0][i] + '</span>';
      })
    .on("click", filterSelect);

}


//Filter Select function. It updates the data, after selecting one option from the filter list
var filterSelect = function(d) {

  data = [{"date":"2018-09-24","Value":"/blue","num":193,"img":"https://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/2012/82/d78470a4-3812-4faf-bfc8-e525d02378d1.png"},{"date":"2018-10-08","Value":"/red","num":127,"img":"https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbows/images/5/5a/Red.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111028211830"},{"date":"2018-09-17","Value":"/green","num":87,"img":"https://www.creativeglassshop.co.uk/userfiles/productlargeimages/product_2747.jpg"}];

  d3.select("svg").remove();

  const newData = data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.Value == d;
  });

  // get the parent ul element, remove `active` class from children
  this.parentNode.childNodes.forEach((e) => {
    e.classList.remove('active');
  });
  // mark this node as active
  this.classList.add('active');
  //Appends chart headline
  
  d3.select(".g-hed").text(d);

  d3.select(".g-intro")
    .html('<a href="https://www.random.com/' + d + '">'+ d +'</a>')    


};

/* ----- !Functions ----- */

/* ----- Main ----- */

filterCreation();
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla);body{font-family:Karla,sans-serif;font-size:18px;overflow:hidden;color:#555}.flex-container{padding:0;margin:0;list-style:none;display:-webkit-box;display:-moz-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:-webkit-flex;display:flex;-webkit-flex-flow:row wrap;justify-content:space-around}.flex-item1,.flex-item2{height:auto;margin-top:10px;font-weight:700;text-align:center}.flex-item1{width:33%}.flex-item2{width:67%}ul{padding:0;list-style-type:none}.selector li{padding:0;margin:0 0 30px}.active img{opacity:.5;filter:alpha(opacity=50)}.selector{max-height:440px;overflow:auto}li .selector{cursor:auto}li .selector img{width:auto;height:100%;max-height:80px}ul::-webkit-scrollbar{width:.8em}.selector::-webkit-scrollbar-track{-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 6px #F5F5F5;background-color:#F5F5F5}.selector::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background-color:#c7003b}.siteText{font-size:2vw}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item1">
    <div id="filter"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item2">
    <p class="g-intro"></p>
    <p class="g-hed"></p>
    <div class="g-chart"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var json_data = {
  "headers": ["Week", "Web Page", "Image", "Number"],
  "rows": [
    ["2018-09-24 00:00:00.0", "/blue", "https://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/2012/82/d78470a4-3812-4faf-bfc8-e525d02378d1.png", 193],
    ["2018-10-08 00:00:00.0", "/red", "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbows/images/5/5a/Red.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111028211830", 127],
    ["2018-09-17 00:00:00.0", "/green", "https://www.creativeglassshop.co.uk/userfiles/productlargeimages/product_2747.jpg", 87]
  ]
};

var dataRows = json_data.rows;

/* ----- !Data ----- */

/* ----- Functions ----- */


//Filter creation function
filterCreation = () => {

  //Clear the filter in case of reload
  d3.select(".selector").remove();

  // Get names of unique Values, for filter list 
  var values = [
    ["/blue", "/red", "/green"],
    ["https://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/2012/82/d78470a4-3812-4faf-bfc8-e525d02378d1.png", "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbows/images/5/5a/Red.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111028211830", "https://www.creativeglassshop.co.uk/userfiles/productlargeimages/product_2747.jpg"]
  ];

  var filter = d3.select("#filter")
    .insert("ul", "svg")
    .classed('selector', true)

  filter.selectAll("li")
    .data(values[0])
    .enter().append("li")
    .html(function(d, i) {
      return '<img src="' + values[1][i] + '"/><br><span class="siteText">' + values[0][i] + '</span>';
    })
    .on("click", filterSelect);

}


//Filter Select function. It updates the data, after selecting one option from the filter list
var filterSelect = function(d) {

  data = [{
    "date": "2018-09-24",
    "Value": "/blue",
    "num": 193,
    "img": "https://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/2012/82/d78470a4-3812-4faf-bfc8-e525d02378d1.png"
  }, {
    "date": "2018-10-08",
    "Value": "/red",
    "num": 127,
    "img": "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/rainbows/images/5/5a/Red.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111028211830"
  }, {
    "date": "2018-09-17",
    "Value": "/green",
    "num": 87,
    "img": "https://www.creativeglassshop.co.uk/userfiles/productlargeimages/product_2747.jpg"
  }];

  d3.select("svg").remove();

  const newData = data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.Value == d;
  });

  // get the parent ul element, remove `active` class from children
  this.parentNode.childNodes.forEach((e) => {
    e.classList.remove('active');
  });
  // mark this node as active
  this.classList.add('active');
  //Appends chart headline

  var gHed = d3.select(".g-hed")

  gHed.html("");

  gHed
    .append('a')
    .attr({
      "xlink:href": '#' + d
    })
    .text(d);

};

/* ----- !Functions ----- */

/* ----- Main ----- */

filterCreation();
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla);
body {
  font-family: Karla, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #555
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around
}

.flex-item1,
.flex-item2 {
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center
}

.flex-item1 {
  width: 33%
}

.flex-item2 {
  width: 67%
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none
}

.selector li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 30px
}

.active img {
  opacity: .5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50)
}

.selector {
  max-height: 440px;
  overflow: auto
}

li .selector {
  cursor: auto
}

li .selector img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 80px
}

ul::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: .8em
}

.selector::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #F5F5F5;
  background-color: #F5F5F5
}

.selector::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #c7003b
}

.siteText {
  font-size: 2vw
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item1">
    <div id="filter"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item2">
    <p class="g-intro"></p>
    <p class="g-hed"></p>
    <div class="g-chart"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your snippet does not work. Possible bad paste that changed a character (guessing it is the quotes)

Comment: Oops. Could have been the es6 template string notation. (Edited)

Comment: Still didn't work. I can see the a tag in the console but the text overrides it so I cannot click on the link.